# Задача с палочками

Tags: математика, олимпиада, дискретная-математика

У Андрея есть палочки с целочисленными длинами и общей длиной 200. Ни из каких трёх нельзя составить треугольник. Какое наибольшее число палочек может быть?

Я знаю что любая палочка должна быть меньше либо равна суммы двух других, но что с этой инфой делать так и не понял.

Comment: Взять одну палочку и постучать по думалке тому, кто написал в условии задачи что из трех палочек нельзя составить треугольник. Разве что палочки кривые ))) Тогда это уже коряги а не палочки. Ну или кукурузные палочки.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, у меня ощущение, что минимальный набор включает палочки

1  1  2  3  5  8 ...

ну, т.е. числа Фибоначчи. Вроде бы всего - 10 палочек:

```
1  1  2  3  5  8  13  21  34
```

эти 9 палочек имеют длину 88. Если возьмем следующую палочку 55, то останется неиспользованной длина 57, и треугольник можно будет сделать. Поэтому приходится брать после палочки 34 палочку длиной 112.

Так что окончательно - 10 палочек.

Comment: тогда их длинна не 200

Comment: @igo Я дописал ответ - так понятнее? Последняя палочка должна быть длиннее очередного числа Фибоначчи и добивать сумму до 200.

Comment: да похоже что вы правы